# Animate increment / decrement number after onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing with the jquery.animateNumber library: https://github.com/aishek/jquery-animateNumber, because from what I see is light and quite fast you can get a nice effect in it. Unfortunately, I have a problem with one thing. I need to decrease the value in the div by 5000 with each click (animating numbers) and decreasing by 5000 also by animating the numbers in the middle. As far as incrementing is concerned, I can not cope with variable decomposition.

How can I solve my problem?

```js
value = parseInt($("#test").html()) * 2;
$("#add").on("click", function() {

  if (value < 50000) {
    $("#test").animateNumber({
      number: value
    });
    value += 5000;
  } else {
    $("#test").html("MAX");
  }

});

$("#delete").on("click", function() {
  $("#test").animateNumber({
    number: value
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-animateNumber/0.0.14/jquery.animateNumber.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" id="delete">Delete</button>
<div id="test">5000</div>
```

Comment: you are saying that you want to increment by `5000` when you click `add` button and decrement `5000` when you click `delete` button, am i right?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam That's right

Comment: see my answer i just posted, if that can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the best I could make it work for you. The trick is to set the `number` property of the target element, which acts as the seed value for when the next animation starts. I removed the "MAX" test for illustration.

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {
    var nextNumber = parseInt($('#test').text(), 10) + 5000;
    $("#test").animateNumber({
      number: nextNumber,
    },
   'normal',
    function() {
        $('#test').prop('number', nextNumber);
      }
    );
});

$("#delete").on("click", function() {
    var nextNumber = parseInt($('#test').text(), 10) - 5000;
  $("#test").animateNumber({
    number: nextNumber
  }, 
  'normal',
   function() {
      $('#test').prop('number', nextNumber);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-animateNumber/0.0.14/jquery.animateNumber.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" id="delete">Delete</button>

<div id="test">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to increment by `5000` when you click `add` button and similarly decrement when click `delete` see below if this is what you wanted

```js
value = parseInt($("#test").html());

$("#add").on("click", function() {
  console.log(value);
  if (value < 50000) {

    value += 5000;
    $("#test").animateNumber({
      number: value
    });
  } else {
    $("#test").html("MAX");
  }

});

$("#delete").on("click", function() {
  value -= 5000;
  $("#test").animateNumber({
    number: value
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-animateNumber/0.0.14/jquery.animateNumber.js"></script>





<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" id="delete">Delete</button>
<div id="test">5000</div>
```

Comment: That's what I meant. Note only that clicking on "add" and then "delete" after the first click remains the same. How can I improve it?

Comment: i just updated an fixed that you can see now refresh the page @sauero

Comment: i don't understand who downvoted it :/ , without even leaving a comment, and this works perfect shouldn't have been downvoted

Comment: I fixed your problem just like you fixed my. Thanks

Comment: you shouldnt downvote on such things please read the community guide for downvoting. @sauero

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: This doesn't work as the OP asked. It recounts from 0 to whatever the next number is. I believe they wanted it to go from 0 to 5000, from 5000 to 10000, etc., without resetting to 0.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Good suggestion, but this guy try to help me. I think that he can't get downvote

Comment: the initial value is picked from the div `#test` whatever you provide there it should increment from there onwards. that's what I did, I hope that makes sense. i was just frustrated that no body explained why downvote, otherwise no offense @Cᴏʀʏ , respect for all!